# Get loading spinner visibility using isDisplay method-Protractor

Tags: javascript, automation, jasmine, protractor

My testcase is to click on a checkbox & soon after its checked there is a spinner progress animation shown which i want to assert if displayed. Using isDisplayed() method always returns me false after clicking on checkbox and my testcase fails, although i could see the spinner animation loading on UI.

Tried the below code which is failing:

```
var checkbox = element(by.id("crucial-one"));
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(checkbox),5000);
checkbox.click();
var spinner = element(by.id("loading-spinner"));
spinner.isDisplayed().then(function(text){
        console.log(text);
    });
expect(spinner.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

HTML code of spinner before clicking on checkbox:

```
<body class="searches">
<div id="loading-spinner" class="wda-overlay" style="display: none;">
    <div class="progress-box" role="region">
        <div class="loader-container large">
            <svg class="loader" viewBox="25 25 50 50">
        </div>
    <div class="msg">Loading...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

HTML code of spinner after clicking on checkbox:

```
<body class="searches">
<div id="loading-spinner" class="wda-overlay" style="display: block;">
    <div class="progress-box" role="region">
        <div class="loader-container large">
            <svg class="loader" viewBox="25 25 50 50">
        </div>
    <div class="msg">Loading...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Expect here as "**browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element))**" will fail Your test case when no loading spinner is visible in given time.

Notice I've changed presenceOf to **visibilityOf**.

```js
it('should show loading-spinner', () => {
  var checkbox = element(by.id("crucial-one"));
  var spinner = element(by.id("loading-spinner"));

  browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(checkbox), 5000);
  checkbox.click();
  browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(spinner), 5000);
});
```

You can also create function to make the code cleaner:

```js
export function waitFor(elm: ElementFinder, waitTime: number): promise.Promise < boolean > {
  return browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(elm), waitTime);
}

// And use it like that:

waitFor(element, 3000);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt work, The html code of this spinner is greyed out and becomes active only after the checkbox click.

Comment: Please provide HTML of Your Spinner before clicking checkbox and HTML of it after clicking checkbox.

Comment: Please check my response inside the question body. Have updated the HTML code as per what you asked for.

Comment: The only difference i see is inside the style tag the value is changing from none to block.

Comment: Looked at Your code and I still believe my solution is good. Before You click "checkbox" Your spinner is in HTML DOM but it is invisible because it has style="display: none;". And it changes it's style to display:block after clicking checkbox - so it starts to be visible. Therefore using browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(spinner), 5000); will make Your test wait, after clicking checkbox, until spinner is visible. If it will be visible - test will pass. If it is invisible - test will fail with timeout.

Comment: I've updated my response above - can You replace your "it" block with mine completely and tell me if it passes or whats the error message if it fails?

Comment: Yes ideally it should have behaved that way but strangely its not getting recognized by this method, even the output of the isDisplayed() method is returning false value everytime although i could visibly see the spinner loading on UI

Comment: its failing though with your IT block - Message:
[31m    Failed: Wait timed out after 5172ms[0m
  Stack:
    TimeoutError: Wait timed out after 5172ms

Comment: Is this loading-spinner inside iframe?

Comment: Nope .. There are no frames in the HTML

Comment: Can You change Your code to this one and tell me if it works?
<div id="loading-message" class="msg">Loading...</div>
var loadingMessage = element(by.id("loading-message"));
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(loadingMessage), 5000);

Comment: No its giving me the same error and failing with timeout error for this particular identifier.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. Answer from Marcin is right, you must use `browser.wait()` with the condition `visibility.Of()`

If the spinner display is short, also use `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)`;